# Combine multiple rows from other table into 1 column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

```
table1

|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      student_id     |   studentname    |     parentid     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |       Kobe       |        1         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |      Lebron      |        1         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|


table2
|---------------------|------------------|
|       parentid      |    parentname    |   
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |      Jordan      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I want to select an output like this

```
result
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|---------------- 
--
|       parentid      |    parentname    |    childrenid    |  childrenname
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------
|          1          |      Jordan      |     1,2          |  Kobe,Jordan
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------
```

is this possible to happen? thanks in advance I already use this query but the rows is duplicating

```
select * from table2 left join table1 ON table1.parentid = table2.parentid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `GROUP_CONCAT` funtion in mysql

```
select parentname,
GROUP_CONCAT(student_id SEPARATOR ',') AS childrenid,
GROUP_CONCAT(studentname SEPARATOR ',') childrenname  
from table2 p left join table1 s on
p.parentid=s.parentid
group by parentname

parentname  childrenid  childrenname
Jordan       1,2        Kobe,Lebron
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d9127/2

Comment: if it helps then please accept my answer as SO appreciation

Comment: btw sir how do I set the length of group_concat?

Comment: @CesarWencester why do you need length if need then you can by usig length funtion

Comment: because I will concat the fullname of each student and when I try the fullname of student is incomplete in the column childrenname

Comment: actually it depends how long the name would be based on your idea you can set that

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible, you have to use left join which will result in two rows one for Kobe and other for Lebron.